# How to copy items in a listbox to another in a different frame

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to take all the items from a listbox and move them to another listbox in another frame.
I tried this but listbox2 wont update when listbox1 is changed.

```
for i in range(listbox1.size()):
    listbox2.insert(i, (listbox2.get(i)))
```

Comment: What have you tried and what issue have you come across? Better provide [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to synchronize the content of the two listboxes, set the `listvariable` option of the two listboxes to the same `StringVar()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk

...
var1 = tk.StringVar()

listbox1 = tk.Listbox(..., listvariable=var1)
...
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(..., listvariable=var1)
...
```